# ubuntu-drivers install throwing error regarding broken packages, what do I need to fix?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, ubuntu-drivers, nvidia-settings

I have just installed Ubuntu on my machine following an online guide.

I am trying to update my Nvidia drivers with the command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Unfortunately this throws an error of:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-455 (= 455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am new to Ubuntu and unsure on how to decipher this issue, does anyone have any insight?

Comment: For extra information running 'dkms status' gives the response:  

nvidia, 450.80.02, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.80.02, 5.4.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)